# SQL Server missing row after entry but using info like its still there

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and for some reason when I added a record it does not show up in the database. It has skipped the number and has saved the information somewhere but I am unable to view it in the table. If I use the login and password everything still works. Why would this happen? Now that I add another record it has moved on to the next number but for some reason row 73 does not show but is stored. Can anyone tell me what causes this or why it may happen when it still is using all the information from what was entered correctly.

[image]

Comment: How are you inserting the record?  Can you please share that query

Comment: is this happening while keeping both the insert connection open and the one querying the data? The transaction may not be fully committed yet. Commit the insert then close that connection, then run a select *.

Comment: How did you get the information from your screenshot? If the record is there you might not have ordered your list by id and by this it only looks like id 73 is not there ...

Comment: Is the first column an IDENTITY column? These can skip values if, for example, an INSERT attempted to write a row but constraints were not satisfied.

Comment: yes this was an identity column its just weird because everything was accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you find your row when searching by id it must be there.

In edit mode the table is not always displayed in order of the ids but by in order of insertion of rows. I experienced this problem myself just like you. Then I queried with "ORDER BY ID" and found everything in place.

Hope that helps anybody experiencing the same problem when using the GUI.